# Cannot translate an object before collision is resolved

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When I compile this is showing

> error: Cannot translate an object before collision is resolved

and when I'm building app for android it shows me an error#5 (null).

Here's my code:

```
function onLocalCollision(meteor, event)
  if event.phase == "began" then
  if event.object1.myName == "meteor" and
     event.object2.myName == "rocket" then
    score = score - 1
    scoreNumber.text = score
    restart.isVisible = true
    meteor.x = 500   
    meteor.y = 300
    meteor2.x = 500
    meteor2.y = 200
    meteor3.x = 500
    meteor3.y = 100
    event.object2.alpha = 0.2
    rocket:applyForce(-150,0,rocket.x,rocket.y)
    lives = lives -1
    livesNumber.text = lives
    if lives < 1 then
    lives = 3
    score = 0
    scoreNumber.isVisible = false
    livesText.isVisible = false
    livesNumber.isVisible=false
    hearticon.isVisible = false
    scoreText.isVisible = false
    gameover.isVisible = true
    restart.x = 100000
    end
  end
  end
end


meteor.collision = onLocalCollision
Runtime:addEventListener("collision", meteor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you cannot translate during a collision (function) so if you just say:`timer.performWithDelay(100, function() rocket:applyForce(-150,0,rocket.x,rocket.y) end, 1)` it should resolve your problem and/or just create a callback function.

> "Modifying Objects
>   The objects involved in the collision should not be removed or any of it's properties altered during a collision event. You should use timer.performWithDelay() if they want to modify object position values or other properties within the collision events.
>
> Removing the object or modifying the properties in the collision event could cause the simulator to crash."

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/collision/index.html